# gdb add new target，like ROCgdb

Tags: gdb

How to add a target to GDB, complete support for a new CPU. I took a look at GDB Internals. I just introduced adding a xxx_tdep.c file, but did not say what information xxx_tdep.c needs to describe in detail. I refer to ROCgdb of RAM architecture, but I don't understand either.

Comment: [Porting the GNU Debugger
Practical Experience with the OpenRISC 1000 Architecture](https://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean3/embecosm-howto-gdb-porting-ean3-issue-2.html) may be helpful.

Comment: thank you,this is a nice designated document.it is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that there is a single document that you can read that contains complete steps for adding a new target.

The best strategy, I think, would be to find a recently added target, and look at the commits that added that target, I would recommend the RISC-V target as being a good example.

I'd start with `git log -- gdb/riscv*` and then start at the bottom of the list and work upwards.

The first commit you find should be [this one](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=dbbb1059e62e9fed10b429c030f76f782cbc1fc4).

The one thing the above doesn't show you though, is that before you can add GDB support, you'll need support for your target in the bfd library (the binutils-gdb/bfd directory), that's how GDB is able to open and process files for your ARCH.  Additionally, if you want GDB to be able to disassemble the instructions for ARCH you'll need to add at least disassembler support to the opcodes library (the binutils-gdb/opcodes directory).  Once you have bfd support and opcodes support things like readelf, objdump, and objcopy either will work, or will require minimal extra effort to get working.  At that point you're ready to start working on GDB.

The ARCH-tdep.[ch] files deal with bare metal target stuff, so every architecture is going to need one of these files.  Then if you want to add Linux support (for example), you'll need ARCH-linux-tdep.[ch] files.  This is generic Linux support, so used by both local and remote Linux targets.  To actually support running GDB natively on Linux for a particular target, you will add ARCH-linux-nat.[ch] files.

Comment: thank you for your advice,In the absence of documentation,this is good advice.